# Cross-platform development solutions for (mobile) performance computing

Tags: performance, cross-platform, scientific-computing, generic-programming

I am looking for a programming language/platform which is suited for handling around 1 to 2 GB of data, and can run signal processing algorithms fast enough across platforms (including modern mobile platforms). Did someone come across suitable solutions?. Please **share** your **research** and **experience** on cross-platform development.

My current research effort is complicated, owing to

- the increased deployment of powerful [mobile] platforms,
- the backing of Java through the popularity of Android (currently the #1 tag on stackoverflow)

I had mixed experience with C# and [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) (It is fast, but cross-platform compatibility can take some additional effort).

I am **not** looking for **High performance computing**(HPC), but into **developing code** with a data and computing-intensive background **that performs well** with as little effort as possible. A case study scenario for this would be Python code which is adapted to the Cython compiler.

I am **not** looking for **UI-centric** projects with solutions such as [Phonegap](https://build.phonegap.com/) and Adobe Air, but I know little about its performance.

**Links**:

- [Cross-Platform Development of High Performance Applications
  Using Generic Programming](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/saxs/researchexam/GenericProgramming.pdf)
- [Native Client: A Sandbox for Portable, Untrusted x86 Native Code](http://research.google.com/pubs/archive/34913.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Yes that is our common denominator. But whereas you start out with HPC and distributed computing, I would like  `distributed` as an optional upgrade a 'la `R`s MPI loop adaptor packages - except that `R` does not run for instance across mobile devices, and is slow...

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps start having a look at [Droidcluster](http://www.ibr.cs.tu-bs.de/papers/buesching-icdcs2012.pdf)